# How to fix a NoMatchingMethodException of Hive UDAF example in Hadoop: the Definitive Guide?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I want to calculate mean of temperature. Then I created a UDAF named 'mean'.
I followed the steps the book suggested and got a NoMatchingMethodException.

```
FAILED: NoMatchingMethodException No matching method for class com.zzy.hadoopbook.hive.Mean with (double). Possible choices: _FUNC_(struct<value:double>)
```

Here is my HiveQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS records3;

CREATE TABLE records3 (year STRING, temperature DOUBLE, quality INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'input/ncdc/micro-tab/sample.txt'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE records3;

ADD JAR hive-examples.jar;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION mean AS 'com.zzy.hadoopbook.hive.Mean';

SELECT mean(temperature) FROM records3;
```

Here is my Java code:

```
package com.zzy.hadoopbook.hive;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDAF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDAFEvaluator;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable;

public class Mean extends UDAF {

    public static class MeanDoubleUDAFEvaluator implements UDAFEvaluator {
        public static class PartialResult {
            double sum;
            long count;
        }

        private PartialResult partial;

        @Override
        public void init() {
            partial = null;
        }

        public boolean iterate(DoubleWritable value) {
            if (value == null) {
                return true;
            }
            if (partial == null) {
                partial = new PartialResult();
            }
            partial.sum += value.get();
            partial.count++;
            return true;
        }

        public PartialResult terminatePartial() {
            return partial;
        }

        public boolean merge(PartialResult other) {
            if (other == null) {
                return true;
            }
            if (partial == null) {
                partial = new PartialResult();
            }
            partial.sum += other.sum;
            partial.count += other.count;
            return true;
        }

        public DoubleWritable terminate() {
            if (partial == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return new DoubleWritable(partial.sum / partial.count);
        }
    }
}
```

My Hive jar version is 1.2.2.
My test cluster Hadoop version is 3.1.0, and Hive version is 2.3.3.

Comment: Your Hive jar version must match the Hive server version, by the way, but what's wrong with the existing `AVG` function?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @cricket_007. The problem is solved after I change my Hive server version into 1.2.2. The existing `AVG` works fine. It's just a practice in Hadoop book which helps readers to understand the mechanism of Hive UDAF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you emulate the official [UDAFExampleAvg.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/udaf/example/UDAFExampleAvg.java) ?

I think the only adjustments you have to make is use `Double` instead of `DoubleWritable` in your `UDAF's` inner classes.

Also see the example [here](https://letsdobigdata.wordpress.com/2016/03/02/writing-hive-udf-and-udaf/) which just uses native `double`. I think that will work too as automatic boxing/unboxing would happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My problem is solved. I think it's the version of server and jar inconsistency. I'm a newbie to Hadoop. Your link really helps me. Now I'm trying to figure out the differences between Double and DoubleWritable.

Comment: @JackieZhao A DoubleWriable is a serialization format for MapReduce. Double is just a Java type

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my life. It's funny that the example of **Maximum** using **IntWritable** works fine while this **Mean** using **DoubleWritable** doesn't work.